# How to determine absolute path of target using bazel query?

Tags: bazel

*Question*

Is there any way I could use `bazel query` or `aspects` to identify where on the package path bazel is picking up a package? Something similar to the `which` command.

The documentation suggests using the `--show_package_location`. However that is deprecated and no longer supported, see [#5592](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5592). Additionally, my attempts at using it have not uncovered much useful information. I have tried `bazel query //some/target/... --output label_kind --show_package_location` as well as other permutations with `bazel build` and it doesn't add output anything different to the console output.

*Motivation*

I have two different directories on my package path for fetch, query and build.

`--package_path=%workspace%:%workspace%/__fuse__`

This configuration supports a workflow where users perform sparse-checkouts of our large repository, while still being able to build code that has not been locally checked out. When building targets, Bazel checks for the locally checked out version of package, and if that doesn't exist, it searches a read only fuse mount.

Sometimes it's unclear to users where a package is getting picked up from, i.e. whether it's the locally checked out version or the one served from fuse. This becomes problematic when they delete or move a Bazel package, and Bazel picks up the version on the fuse mount.

It'd be nice if I could point them to a command that would map each package to where it's being picked up. For example, if i ran the command on ...

```
//some/package/foo --> package_path/some/package/foo
//some/package/bar --> other_package_path/some/package/bar
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I completely missed this in the bazel query documentation.

With bazel query, I simply needed to add `--output location`, so provided I make a query like:

```
bazel query //some/package/... --output location
```

Then bazel query will output

```
/absolute/path/some/package/BUILD:lineno:colno target_kind label
```

for each target in `//some/package/...`